# How can I allow a user to tap on words in an article and upgrade the article model in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I am actually asking if anyone is so kind to get me out of this hole.
I am learning python /django/posgres and I got to a point where I don't really know what to do next and I would appreciate some direction!

I am designing this webapp for my students. The idea is that they can read texts and be able to tap on the words and mark them as learnt (for example: red for unknown words and green for known words) and I want every user to keep their modified text.

At first I tought of jquery (which seems to be an old tool) but of course data is not overwritten.

One of the approaches I tought of was some kind of post request as if it were a form... make every word to behave like a button. I dunno.

I think I am somehow wrong in my approach. How would you approach this? What do you suggest me to read? I am not only trying to solve this but I am also trying to learn . Thanks in advance.

This is what I did so far:

https://billsiosoreadingposgres.herokuapp.com/

I was inspired by the following webpage:

https://www.lingq.com/

### **Part of My code below**

'''

```
**model**

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    body = RichTextField(default = 'body')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300, default='brief description')
    audio = models.TextField(max_length=300, default='audio')
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


**Article view**

class ArticleListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_list.html'
    login_url = 'login'
```

### '''

Comment: Your ask is a big one. It is not impossible but nothing simple comes to mind.  You will need A LOT of javascript and a backend to support this aspect.  I can see the solution and it is complicated. Interested to see what others come up with as suggestions (hopefully simpler)